# Installing openSuSE from pendrive

Tags: usb, installation, opensuse-11.3

Back then I found so many good howtos about this but now, I can't find any of them. Even the ones pointing to the openSuSE wiki have been deleted. One wild guess is Unetbootin, but I doubt it'd work. (Usually it never works as it should.)

Comment: Currently I'm copying the installation files, it takes a while.

Comment: Guys: The Unetbootin doesn't work. The ISO is not meant to be used like this (you need sysinstall and all). In my personal opinion, we'd need a .img disk image for this. Those are the ones for USB purpose, but I can't find any on the OpenSUSE site. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Dec 2012 (openSUSE 12.2), all the other answers to this question are wrong.

**To create a bootable openSUSE USB drive, you must use [openSUSE Image Writer](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick).** There are versions for Windows and Linux.

I've just successfully booted openSUSE 12.2 from a USB stick. The boot option to check the integrity of the medium froze, but the live OS works fine.

Comment: True, and agreed. Though, it took them long enough to make such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Install SUSE to a USB Flash Drive using the CD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-suse-flash-drive-install/)

> This tutorial covers the process of creating a SUSE Linux USB Flash Drive using the OpenSUSE Live CD. This tutorial works much like the install to an External USB Hard drive with the exception that the user is performing a full OpenSUSE install to a USB flash drive. The process does differ slightly! This tutorial was made possible due to a custom Portable SUSE script created and provided by James Rhodes. Please note that due to the limited number of write functions a flash drive can handle before going bad, you may reduce the life of your flash drive by performing this installation.

Comment: But noünoüno. I want to install it TO my PC.. not to a pendrive. To my internal Sata HDD. The howto covers the installing it to the pendrive. (No problem / hard feelings, but this is not the one. Thanks though :))

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-help-here/install-boot-login/443077-installing-pendrive.html

I'll update this answer when we get an answer/solution. Thanks for all the tips though, sad thing they didn't work. :/

Comment: So you want to install from a pendrive to your HDD? Unetbootin doesn't support openSUSE; you can [create a bootable stick with LiveWriter](http://superuser.com/a/526162/33589). Did you have problems after that step?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official or easy way of doing this sadly. The live image can be copied, but you are doomed if you want to use the DVD.

Answer (score -1):

Have you *tried* UNetBootin?  I really like it, and it's worked well for me in the past.  If it doesn't work, you could try Fedora's [LiveUSB-Creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/).  And I'm guessing that, if you could boot successfully from the flash drive, there'd be no problems using the built-in installer.  Finally, it may be possible to copy the contents of the *.iso directly to the flash drive via `dd` like this:

```
dd if=/path/to/opensuse.iso of=/dev/sda1
```

where "/dev/sda1" is the flash drive's device name.  Please also note that the flash drive must be unmounted (but not ejected) for this last option to work.  To be honest, though, I'm not sure how stable this last method is, so I'd really recommend UNetBootin or the LiveUSB-Creator.  Good luck!

Comment: it should be the full device ie, `sda` not the partition partition `sda1`. Last method will fail if you choose to write to a partition. Personal experience.

Comment: When I do this UNetbootin style, it won't even boot. I choose it at boot but nothing happens, W7 loads.

Comment: I'm not surprised Unetbootin didn't work - TBH Unetbootin and openSUSE never seem to get along :(

Comment: @Sathya: Yes, you're right.  I forgot about the `sda` v. `sda1` issue.

Comment: To create a bootable openSUSE USB drive, you must use LiveWriter. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/526162/33589).

Comment: @Sathya What is the sda v. sda1 issue?

Comment: @PranitBauva `sda` refers to the entire device, while `sda1` refers to one partition